# Confirming behavior for "sudo su - someuser"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, passwords, sudo, su

I am logged in as `myuser`.

When doing `su - someuser` I need to give password for user `someuser`

I tried this `sudo su - someuser` and I had to give only my password.

My question is why didn't I have to give password of `someuser` ? Is it because the leading `sudo` gave me `root` privilege and so I did not need to give password for `someuser` ?

Which man page is this documented ?

Answer (score 1):

You are asked your own password because you are using `sudo`.

And yes, `su` asks for the password of the target user when not called by root. See [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101341/su-user-doesnt-work-for-users-without-a-password)

Which means that you could instead use a plain `su someuser` (no `sudo`) and then give the password of the target user.